# How to pointing a structure in procedure in C?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, typedef

I have a structure like this

```
typedef struct{
   int stat;
}dot;
```

And I would like to acces this structure in a procedure like this

```
void change(dot *stat){
    stat[5][5].stat = 5;
}

int main(){
    dot mydottes[10][10];
    mydottes[5][5].stat = 3;
    change(&mydottes);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compiled this, it return errors. So how to pointing a structure in a procedure?

Best Regards

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follows:

```
void change(dot stat[][10]){ // <<<
    stat[5][5].stat = 5;
}

int main(){
    dot mydottes[10][10];
    mydottes[5][5].stat = 3;
    change(mydottes); // <<<
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works for 1 dimensional array, I'm sorry, my problems is 2 dimensional array (I have edited my question)

Comment: OK - I have updated my answer now - please be more careful when asking questions in future, otherwise people waste time and effort answering the "wrong" question.

Comment: I don't know why it still return like this

stu.c: In function ‘main’:
stu.c:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘change’ from incompatible pointer type

Comment: Did you make *both* the changes I highlighted with `<<<` above ?

Comment: Oh! I have edited it! The big of the dot is put into the structure. Thanks alot Mr. Paul! Your answer is works!